# Finding functions to prove the termination of my specific rewrite system

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to prove the termination of some rewrite system by defining a size function for the terms. We know that a rewrite system terminates if the size of the terms is increasing after every rewrite step.

In the system I have elements $n$ and $s$ and functions $a$ and $r$, we have $l$ as an arbitrary combination the functions applied on the elements, we also call $l$ an expression. The rewrite system is

$$ \begin{align*} 
a(n,l) & \rightarrow l \\ 
a(l,n) & \rightarrow l \\
a(a(l_1,l_2),l_3) &\rightarrow a(l_1,a(l_2,l_3)) \\
r(n) &\rightarrow n \\ 
r(s) &\rightarrow s \\
r(a(l_1,l_2)) & \rightarrow a(r(l_2),r(l_1))\\
r(r(l)) & \rightarrow l
\end{align*}$$

I want to make a size function to prove the termination of the rewrite system. We know that the rewrite system will terminate if we can find a size function such that for every rewrite rule it holds that $$expr_1 \rightarrow expr_2 \Rightarrow size (expr_2) \lt size (expr_1)$$

We can define the size function for $n$ and $s$ as $size(n) =1 $ and $size(s) =1$, but we also want to define a size function for $size(a(l_1,l_2)$ and $size(r(l))$. The hard part is to choose this $size$ function right for the third and last two rewrite rules.

To reduce this problem, we can also say that we want to find two functions $f_1: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} $ and $f_2: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ where $0 \not\in \mathbb{N}$.

Where we want that for all $n,m,p \in \mathbb{N}$ that,

1. $n \lt f_1 ( f_1 (n) )$
2. $f_2(n , f_2(m, p) ) \lt f_2(f_2(n, m),p)$
3. $f_2( f_1 ( n) , f_1(m)) \lt f_1 ( f_2(m, n)) $

To satisfy the first two conditions, we can for example choose $$ f_1(n) = n + 1 $$ and $$ f_2(n,m) = 2n + m + 1,$$

but I cannot come up with something that also satisfies the third condition. I have tried to add some squares, but that did not help me.

Does anyone have an idea for a function that would work, or have a proof that there do not exist such functions? I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: Initial thoughts: I'm fairly confident that if we assume $f_1$ is increasing, then we can simply take it to be $n\mapsto n+1$ via some transport of structure argument. In that case, the third condition says that $f_2$ is non-*increasing* (!) along the diagonal, so in particular is eventually constant on the diagonal. If it were *actually* constant $f_2(k,k)=c$ then $n=m=p=c$ would violate the second condition. (Actually, all we need is a fixpoint.) Therefore, my guess is that these functions doesn't exist... but this is far from a proof, of course.

Comment: Well that turned out to be nonsense; see my Answer. But just to make sure I'm understanding: the first two rewrite rules also imply that we need $k<f_2(1,k)$ and $k<f_2(k,1)$, right?

Comment: It is true that we also want that $k< f_2(1, k)$ and $k < f_2(k,1)$ hold, but I had the idea that that is an easy requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Despite my naysaying in the comments, this can be done. Take

$$f_1(n)=\begin{cases} 4^n & n>1 \\ 2 & n=1 \end{cases} \quad\text{ and }\quad f_2(n,m)=n(m+1)$$

The first condition is clearly satisfied, and for the second:
\begin{align*}
f_2(n,f_2(m,p)) &= n(m(p+1)+1)=n[m(p+1)+1] \\
f_2(f_2(n,m),p) &= n(m+1)(p+1)=n[m(p+1)+(p+1)]
\end{align*}

Finally, it remains to check that $f_2(f_1(n),f_1(m))<f_1(f_2(m,n))$. There are four cases:

- If $m>1$ and $n>1$, then $4^n(4^m+1) < 4^{(n+1)+m} < 4^{nm+m}$.
- If $m>1$, then $f_2(f_1(1),f_1(m)) =(2)(4^m+1)<4^{2m} = f_1(f_2(m,1))$.
- If $n>1$, then $f_2(f_1(n),f_1(1))=f_2(4^n,2)=4^n\cdot 3<4^{n+1}=f_1(f_2(1,n))$.
- Finally, $f_2(2,2)=6<16=f_1(2)$.

---

**Commentary**

From your example in the Question, it seems that you also had the intuition that I did, that $f_2$ needs to "place more weight" on the first argument. One of the "tricks" here is to observe that if we try placing that weight on the second argument instead, then the second condition is actually saying that in the iteration, $f_2$ needs to reward balancing those weights rather than piling it on the same side. This strongly suggests a quadratic function, since famously you get more area by growing both sides of a rectangle than by growing one side twice (i.e., squares have larger area than rectangles of the same perimeter).

The other trick is that the third condition implies that $f_1(N)$ needs to grow a lot faster than $f_2(N,N)$ (this is really the only legacy of the $n+1$ idea in my comment). Initially I guessed $2^{2^n}$, but there are essential difficulties with exponentials at $n=m=1$. So I baked in an exception to handle that explicitly, and when trying the calculations noticed that with some tweaking we could eliminate the second exponential. (Probably something like $f_1(n)=4^n-2$ also works, but I decided I'd rather handle cases than worry about minus signs in the inequalities, haha.)

Comment: Thank you very much. I checked and $f(n) = 4^2 -2 $ will indeed also work.